# PHP 5.4.7,Apache,win7,sqlite. Error info: Call to undefined function sqlite_open()

Tags: php, apache, sqlite

My environment:
PHP 5.4.7
Apache
win7
DB is sqlite. 
I have already uncomment out below script

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

But it still shows the Error info: Call to undefined function sqlite_open().

below is my php test code.
Anyone can help me?

```
<?php
phpinfo();
$db = sqlite_open('d:/testsqlite');
$rs = sqlite_query($db, 'select * from testtable');
print_r(sqlite_fetch_all($rs));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only uncommented the extensions and it does not quarantee that it will work

You can:
Check if it's properly loaded, by executing `phpinfo()` function or `php -i` on your `CLI`, if it's not then check the server error logs (apache?) probably you will get more details, why extensions is not loaded.

EDIT1:

You have sqlite3 version you need to call sqlite class method statically like 
[sqlite3::open()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php)

Here is [query example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php).

And you can always can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mysqlitedb.db');
```

[Connecting to PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: what the phpinfo() shows seems nothing wrong.My doubt is what should i config for the param sqlite3.extension_dir=???

Comment: Ah you have sqlite3, then you need to call your functions like sqlite3::open()

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much indeed.That is my mistake. I called the nobeing function. Thank you. I don't like to use the pdo, because it need to create the odbc.One more question, Is the performance of PDO type better than the sqlite3 function?

Comment: I tested with pdo, no need to config odbc.foolish me